# Python UnicodeDecodeError while loading GloVec model

Tags: python, utf-8

I am doing sentiment analysis on a roman urdu data set present in a `.csv` file.
After cleaning the data, the data is located in `X_sentiment_train['text']`.
Then, I am assigning the data to sentences with this list comprehension:

```
sentences = [sentence if isinstance(sentence, list) else [sentence] for sentence in X_sentiment_train['text'].values]
```

After getting the text in variable sentences, I train the GloVec model with my dataset, and save the model as such:

```py
corpus = Corpus()

corpus.fit(sentences, window=10)
glove = Glove(no_components=5, learning_rate=0.05)
glove.fit(corpus.matrix, epochs=30, no_threads=4, verbose=True)
glove.add_dictionary(corpus.dictionary)
glove.save("gloves.model")
```

After that I load my model as follows:

```py
glove_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('gloves.model', binary=False, unicode_errors='ignore')
```

However, on loading I get this error:

`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: That means the file isn't using UTF8. You'll have to find what the actual encoding is. You can use a library like chardet to try and detect the encoding

Comment: thanks, i am done with, glove_model = Glove.load("gloves.model", binary=False,  unicode_errors='ignore')